# how to fix "Error in textConnection(text) : all connections are in use" in R?

Tags: r, split

In R I tried to read a fairly large csv file (4200KB) but encountered the following error. It is strange that I ran the same command before without any problem. The only thing changed was I recently updated my R from 3.01 to 3.03. Not sure this would affect anything.

If anyone has a thought/experience on how to fix it, it would be much appreciated!

```
> xml2csv(xmlFile,csvFile)

 Error in textConnection(text) : all connections are in use 

>traceback()

9 textConnection(text) 

8 read.table(text = data, sep = sep, fill = TRUE, row.names = NULL, 
    header = FALSE, blank.lines.skip = FALSE, strip.white = TRUE, 
    col.names = paste("v", sequence(max(x)))) 

7 read.concat(a, names(data[split.col]), sep) 

6 concat.split.compact(data = data, split.col = split.col, sep = sep, 
    drop = drop, fixed = fixed) 

5 concat.split(data[split.cols[x]], split.cols[x], seps[x], drop = TRUE) 

4 FUN(1:686[[125L]], ...) 

3 lapply(seq_along(split.cols), function(x) {
    concat.split(data[split.cols[x]], split.cols[x], seps[x], 
        drop = TRUE)
}) 

2 concat.split.multiple(Y, as.vector(colnames(Y))[-c(1:2)], ":") at IFN_functions.r#115

1 xml2csv(xmlFile, csvFile)
```

Comment: close your `textConnection`! read `?textConnection` and the clue lies in `?showConnections`, a link to that will be found if you READ `?textConnection` thoroughly!

Comment: do you use closeAllConnections()? the error persists after it though, why? See comment below...

Comment: It's possible that you also updated "splitstackshape" during a routine package update process. The `textConnection` was added in later when I introduced `count.fields` to determine the number of columns ultimately required by `read.table`.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is fairly self-explanatory; all text connections are in use :). Are you using other connections in the code? And if so, are you closing them after you're done with them with     close(con)?

Comment: Thanks! I use showConnections() but did not find any user created connection there. I used closeAllConnections() before calling the xml2csv() function, but the error is still there. >showConnections(all = FALSE)
         description class mode text isopen can read can write    
    > showConnections(all = T)    
      description class      mode text   isopen   can read can write
    0 "stdin"     "terminal" "r"  "text" "opened" "yes"    "no"     
    1 "stdout"    "terminal" "w"  "text" "opened" "no"     "yes"    
    2 "stderr"    "terminal" "w"  "text" "opened" "no"     "yes"

Comment: I had the same error when I used the XML package calling xmlRoot(xmlTreeParse(string)) and looping/sapplying over many strings. Adding a closeAllConnections() after each call worked, but is probably a complete hack. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The limit of maximum number of open connections is currently set to be 128. It is hardcoded into the R source code as constant / macro NCONNECTIONS in src/main/connections.c

You may look at the workaround posted on Wishlist for R: https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/Wishlist-for-R/issues/28